# Multi-Table join need max version for each side

Tags: sql, join, optimization

So I have two tables T1 and T2 - originally only one had a "version" field, now they both do and I need the join between the two to account for that.

```
T1 {
modifyTime dateTime
id int
version int
ruleId int
.....
} 

T2 {
modifyTime DateTime
id int
version int
.....
}
```

My old query was :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ruleid = t2.id 
JOIN (SELECT max(version) AS version,id 
      FROM t1 GROUP BY id) b ON t1.id=b.id AND t1.version=b.version
```

Now I need the same query but the max version on T2 to also be considered.  Tried adding another JOIN like the third, but that returned nothing.  Also the entry in T2 may be blank, I mean `T1.ruleId` may be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which RDBMS you're using. If yours supports the `WITH` clause, that might make the statement read a little cleaner.

In any case, I think you were on the right track. The fact that ruleId may be `NULL` complicates things, but [something like this (Fiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/428086/24) should work:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
 FROM (SELECT t1.*
         FROM t1
         JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(version) AS "VERSION"
                 FROM t1
                GROUP BY id) MAX_T1  ON MAX_T1.id = t1.id 
                                    AND MAX_T1.version = t1.version
      ) t1
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.*
              FROM t2
              JOIN (SELECT t2.id, MAX(t2.version) AS "VERSION"
                      FROM t2
                     GROUP BY t2.id) MAX_T2  ON MAX_T2.id = t2.id 
                                            AND MAX_T2.version = t2.version
           ) t2 ON t2.id = t1.ruleId
;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  It was a little confusing with the reuse of t1 and t2 all over, but I got the gist.