# INNER JOIN versus LIMIT for version

Tags: sql, join, optimization

In my first question [Multi-Table join need max version for each side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275017/multi-table-join-need-max-version-for-each-side) I am using INNER JOINs to merge two tables who both have 'version' columns that need to be adhered to.  My question is - what's the difference between this and doing a `LIMIT 1` on the end of the outter queries with an `ORDER BY version`?  Would that be faster?  Does it even work the same way?

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.*
 FROM (SELECT t1.*
         FROM t1 ORDER BY t1.id, t1.version LIMIT 1) t1
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.* FROM t2 ORDER by t2.id, t2.version LIMIT 1) t2 
    ON t2.id = t1.ruleId;
```

Comment: "Does it even work the same way" --- just have a look on the execution plan. "Would that be faster?" --- it might as soon as now DB engine knows you only need one row.

Comment: PS: the nested query for `FROM` clause looks redundant though, why to even nest it?

Answer (score 1):

Your query may not return the correct result.

First of all you probably wanted to use `DESC` to get the MAX version:

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.*
 FROM (SELECT t1.*
         FROM t1 ORDER BY t1.id, t1.version DESC LIMIT 1) t1
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.* FROM t2 ORDER by t2.id, t2.version DESC LIMIT 1) t2 
    ON t2.id = t1.ruleId;
```

But even with this correction there will be the cases where there will no match.

Take for example this case:

```
t1:
id ruleid version
1  1      1
1  2      2
2  1      1
2  2      2
2  3      3
```

your sub-query for t1 will select this row:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t1 ORDER BY t1.id, t1.version DESC LIMIT 1

t1:
id ruleid version
1  2      2
```

It will return a row for id=1 always. Even when you add id with #3 and version #100, the `LIMIT` clause will restrict the selection according to your `ORDER BY t1.id, t1.version DESC` clause

Now, let's check t2. For t2 to have these values:

```
t2:
id version
1  1
1  2
2  1
2  2
2  3
```

the subquery will select this row:

```
SELECT t2.* FROM t2 ORDER by t2.id, t2.version DESC LIMIT 1

t2:
id version
1  2
```

As you can see, t2.id will not join with t1.ruleid

The query that was proposed as an answer to your previous question:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
 FROM (SELECT t1.*
         FROM t1
         JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(version) AS "VERSION"
                 FROM t1
                GROUP BY id) MAX_T1  ON MAX_T1.id = t1.id 
                                    AND MAX_T1.version = t1.version
      ) t1
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.*
              FROM t2
              JOIN (SELECT t2.id, MAX(t2.version) AS "VERSION"
                      FROM t2
                     GROUP BY t2.id) MAX_T2  ON MAX_T2.id = t2.id 
                                            AND MAX_T2.version = t2.version
           ) t2 ON t2.id = t1.ruleId
;
```

will return the proper match: t2.id will match t1.ruleid

BTW, you can use your query only for a "known" ID. E.g. if you need to select max versions for ID=3, the query will look like this:

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.*
 FROM (SELECT t1.*
         FROM t1 WHERE ruleid=3 ORDER BY t1.id, t1.version DESC LIMIT 1) t1
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.* FROM t2 WHERE id=3 ORDER by t2.id, t2.version DESC LIMIT 1) t2 
    ON t2.id = t1.ruleId
 WHERE t2.id = 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

You want the newest t1, and its newest t2.  Right?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM       t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t2.id = t1.ruleId
ORDER BY t1.version DESC, t2.version DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Only returns a single row.

Comment: I have trouble understanding how your original query returns more than a single row.  You are joining the result of one query on t1, limited to one result, to another query on t2, limited to one result.  How can that return more than one row?